# Can only get HTML code using ajax, jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, text, return-value

I can only get result with HTML tag, but I just want the text result.
My js is:

```
    $("#login").click(function() {
    var u = $("#username").val();
    var p = $("#password").val();
    //alert(u+" "+p);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'login.jsp',
        data:'username='+u+'&password='+p,
        dataType:'text',
        success:function(data, status, xhr){
            alert(data);
        }

    });
```

And the login.jsp is:

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="Database.DB" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/plain; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>      
<%
    //get all parameters
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if(true)
        out.print(username);
    else
        out.println("");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

But the alert just gives me a html code, however, I only need the "text" part. Already set the dataType to "text", but it's not working.

Please, any help, really appreciate it!

Comment: Then remove all the html from login.jsp

Comment: But I'm not responding html right? I just print out the username...

Comment: Everything outside `<% ... %>` will be in the response.

Comment: I removed everything outside <% ... %>, but still get text and many spaces. Hence I cannot decide if the response is equals to username... really appreciate your help.. It's weird, I should be able to get just the text result right?

Comment: As long as you're using jQuery, look into [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Comment: yes, thank you. I've trim it. However I'm still confusing how can I just get text response?

Comment: If you want just text why would you output html? Your jsp page should only include what you actually want in the response, which in this case means no html tags.

Comment: I actually don't know how to get response from AJAX, I thought this is the way you capture ajax response - using output.. So what is the correct way then? Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Sorry, to clarify what I meant in my last comment, _outside of `<%` and `%>` tags_ your jsp page should only include what you actually want in the response, so if you want plain text don't put any html tags. You can have as much server-side code as you like inside `<% ... %>` tags.

Comment: I see. It's very helpful, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function for an ajax request, if you want the specific text in an html tag, you have to do the following (for this example in a login scenario)

```
$("#login").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'login.jsp',
    data:{username:$("#username").val(), password:$("#password").val()},
    dataType:'text',
    success:function(data, status, xhr){
        //to find the text inside the body tag, first we have to 
        //check if there are a body tag using a regular expression.
        var matchBodyTagText = data.match(/<body[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/body>/ig);
        if(matchBodyTagText){
            // The body tag exists, now we have to get only the text inside. 
            // There are described two ways to extract the text inside, but may be there are many other ways

            // 1 : with split, slice and join native methods in Javascript
            console.log(matchBodyTagText[0].split("<body")[1].split(">").slice(1).join(">").split("</body>")[0]);
            // 2 : With JQuery
            console.log($(matchBodyTagText[0]).text());
        }else{
            //Do something else
        }
    }

});
}
```

I hope was helpful .